# Tensorflow model comes through as a tuple when I run it on a separate class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, oop

I'll try to explain this as clearly as I can and hopefully someone can help.

I was training a Tensorflow model using a dataset and then using it to make predictions. I had everything under one .py file and it worked well but the code was very long.

```
actual_data['PredictedValue'] = model.predict(normed_actual_data)
```

Decided to have the model train on a separate python file, under its own class class and return it from a function.

However, if I print(type(model)) from within the class I get this:

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>
```

But if I run the same print(type(model)) command after the function has returned "model", I get this:

```
<class 'tuple'>
```

The problem is that I can no longer run model.predict methods against this type of object.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, please can you share reproducible to replicate your issue, so that i can help you. Thanks!